# How do I add another div id to setInterval load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this `AJAX` script that refreshes/updates a `div` with the id `#main`.

Is it possible to add yet another id `#count` to also refresh/update along with the other where it says `/// can add another function here`

I don't know `javascript` or `ajax` but I've tried to add `function timingLoad() { $('#count').load(' #count', function()` and just `$('#count').load(' #count', function()` but without any luck to get it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
  setInterval(timingLoad, 3000);

  function timingLoad() {
    $('#main').load(' #main', function() {
      /// can add another function here
    });
  }
}); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to load the current page (via AJAX) at regular intervals and extract the contents of two separate HTML elements (`#main` and `#count`).

I would use `jQuery.get()` instead of `.load()` for this

```js
$.get().done(doc => {
  $("#main").html($("#main", doc))
  $("#count").html($("#count", doc))
})
```

This loads the current page via `$.get()` then sets the HTML content of `#main` and `#count` with their counterparts from the loaded document.